missed comma between flow collection entries in yaml file
trying to solve this issue.
I have a snippe of code:
  {{- with .Values.taxnorway.service.ports }}
  ports:
  {{ toYaml . | nindent 2 }}
  {{- end }}

Every time I try to do someting/fixing I get this error in lint tool:

Ehat is reffering to is from values.yaml:
  service:
    name: taxnorway
    ports:
      - name: http
        port: 80
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 8080
      - name: https
        port: 443
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 8443

Do you have any idea how to fix that?

You're feeding something that isn't YAML into a linter that works on YAML.
Your input is from the looks of it a Go text/template (possibly Helm). This input is processed into YAML but is not YAML itself. In particular, the {{- ... }} syntax is text/template syntax.
Since the input contains non-YAML syntax, a YAML linter is not a viable tool to check it. So the fix is to not use a linter, or use one that works on text/template'd YAML (I am not aware of the existence of such a linter).
